# Truffle Compile with Solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile

I just upgraded my code to Solidity 0.5 and am trying to use the truffle framework with it. I did update my code in Remix and it does seem to work.

The problem I have is that I am unable to compile my code with truffle. I get this error message:

> SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current
>   compiler is 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang - note that
>   nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released
>   version pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

I have reinstalled truffle, tried it with the beta version (by first running `npm -g uninstall truffle` and then running `npm -g install truffle@beta`, reinstalled `solc`, but nothing seems to work so far. Does anybody have any idea about what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you changed the compiler version in your contracts? (Including the migration files?)

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall nvm and node and then uninstalled and reinstalled truffle@beta and now it just gives me another error. Now I am getting this error though: "UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct Locational.LocationPredicate memory" not yet implemented." which is really strange as the code works on Remix.

Comment: @Emul Your instructions can be usefull to someone else that want to use solc 0.5 with Truffle. Can you add them as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by uninstalling and reinstalling nvm and node and then uninstalling and reinstalling truffle@beta. 
It could be that for some reason something was installed wrong (or didn't work with a later version) therefore creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Pragma. I just did it. It works fine

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

Comment: I already did that. It was after I updated my code with the 0.5 needed updates that it still wasn't compiling. It was only by uninstalling and reinstalling a bunch of things that I managed to make it work.